# Things that I didn't understand during the deployment of the Gnosis Safe contracts on an EVM-based chain

Tags: ethereum, smartcontracts, .env, gnosis-safe

I want to check my assumptions on things that I didn't fully understand during [the deployment](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-contracts/blob/v1.3.0/README.md#custom-networks) of the Gnosis Safe contracts on an EVM-based chain.

**I would appreciate it if you could help me verify my assumptions about the deployment.**

- Three steps below are needed to complete the Safe deployment.

  1. Make a request for a new deployment at https://github.com/safe-global/safe-singleton-factory.
  2. Deploy the Safe contracts on a custom network.
  3. Add the newly supported network to the safe-deployments repository located at https://github.com/safe-global/safe-deployments.
- The purpose of the first step is to employ a deterministic deployment proxy which allows the contracts' addresses to be predetermined.
- The second step requires having coins from the custom network, and this is the only purpose for adding the MNEMONIC to the `.env` file.
- Format of the MNEMONIC variable in the `.env` file is:

  ```bash
  MNEMONIC="antique assume recycle glance agent habit penalty forum behave danger crop weekend"
  ```
- The only purpose of including ETHERSCAN_API_KEY in `.env` is to update the Safe contracts code on the Etherscan.

**Below is something that I cannot even begin to guess the purpose of:**

- What is the purpose of the third step? Is the purpose of this to document the deployments of the custom networks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got it right. Adding your deployment to that repository will inform everyone that your chain has the Gnosis Safe singleton contract.

This repository is associated with an [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@gnosis.pm/safe-deployments), which the Gnosis Safe SDK depends on. This means that after adding your network, the SDK will be able to deploy and use contracts form your chain.

Comment: Thanks for your response to one part of my question. Can you help me verify my assumptions about the other part?